# How to add to a listBox only the left part of dictionary<string, string>?

Tags: c#, winforms

At the top of the form

```
Dictionary<string, string> FileList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

In the constructor

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
      
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, "test.txt")))
    {
        string g = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, "test.txt"));
        FileList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(g);
        listBox1.DataSource = FileList.ToList();
    }
```

instead making :

```
listBox1.DataSource = FileList.ToList();
```

and then in the listBox i will see for example "hello", "d:\test\test1.txt"

I want that in the listBox there will be only : "hello"

I don't want to change the FileList but to change what will be adding from the FileList to the listBox and that is only the left side.

another problem might be with the listBox selected index :

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem;
    var itemCast = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)item;
    pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(itemCast.Value);
}
```

in one hand i don't want to see in the listBox the right side the values in the other hand i want the selected index event to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary maps keys to values. What you call *"left part/side"* is actually the key, and the other element is the value.

C# [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0) has a property: [`Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-keys) which returns only the **keys** in the dictionary (e.g. your `"hello"` string).

Therefore you can use:

```
listBox1.DataSource = FileList.Keys.ToList();
```

*Note that if you ever need only the **values** (e.g. `"d:\test\test1.txt"` etc.), `Dictionary` has a similar property: [`Values`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-values).*

Comment: if I'm using your solution in the constructor : listBox1.DataSource = FileList.Keys.ToList(); then when running the application it's getting to the selectedindex event and give error on the line : var itemCast = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)item; System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: The selected `item` will no longer be a `KeyValuePair`, but a simple `string`. You can use this string as a key to your dictionary to get the value: `var val =  FileList[(string)item];`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that, when the user selects a key, you're going to want to get the corresponding value. In that case, rather than just binding the keys, bind the whole `Dictionary`:

```cs
myListBox.DisplayMember = "Key"
myListBox.ValueMember = "Value"
myListBox.DataSource = myDictionary.ToArray()
```

Each item is a `KeyValuePair`, which has `Key` and `Value` properties. The code above will display the keys and then, when the user selects an item, you can get the corresponding value from the `SelectedValue` property.

Note that data-binding like this requires an `IList`, while the `Dictionary` only implements `ICollection`. For that reason, you need to call `ToArray` or `ToList` to create an `IList` for binding.